# Analytics for ROS debian packages?

Tags: ros, debian, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any official / public / private websites that provide statistics or analytics regarding download patterns for Debian releases of ROS packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195193/analytics-for-ros-debian-packages?/) by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I know of.

OSFR does check the logs of the servers serving their package repositories and mirrors, but given the fact that there are 7 other mirrors not under OSRF control, those numbers don't give you a complete picture.

The latest ROS [metrics report](http://download.ros.org/downloads/metrics/metrics-report-2014-07.pdf) also mentions this ("Binary Downloads – July 2014", page 17):

> Source: Apache2, counting only downloads from the main repository [..]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1